# Axios error after upgrading from v0.27.2 to v1.1.2

Tags: javascript, axios

After upgrading from Axios v0.27.2 to v1.1.2, I get an error in the following because `response.error` now returns `undefined`

```js
import axios from 'axios'

const axiosInstance = axios.create({ baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080' })
export default axiosInstance

// the definition of the functions saveNewToken, showError have been 
// omitted in the interest of brevity
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(saveNewToken, error => {

  // The error occurs here because error.response is undefined
  switch (error.response.status) {
    case 400:
      showError(error.response.data, 'Validation error: please correct any errors before re-submitting')
      break
  }
  return Promise.reject(error)
})
```

So I guess the response interceptors API changed such that `error.response` is not a valid property of the argument passed to the `onRejected` handler.

I've read through the Axios release notes and looked for a v1 migration guide for a list of required changes, but I can't find anything specific about API changes in v1.

Comment: I think it was `undefined` since the beginning  , I have "^0.27.2" with typescript and it shows its as optional param (undefined). and if you see source of [`axios-0.x`](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/c4bf0a4afcac9a49e9b58d3ea64570110cba34f8/lib/core/AxiosError.js#L29) it further confirms.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple issues submitted regarding `error`s for 1.1.2

For example:

> After upgrading form v0.27.2 to v1.1.2 import error with Vite
>
> Build shows warning:
> Non-existent export 'AxiosError' is imported from node_modules/axios/index.js

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5118

And

> Describe the bug
> AxiosHeaders, AxiosError, CanceledError and Axios are "exported" in the type definitions index.d.ts, but not exported in the module.

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5031

So I think your issue is related. It's maybe a good idea to wait for these issues get fixed.